# ¿Cómo cambiar el campo value de form desde el controlador en Symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony2

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de reservas y estoy guardando desde un formulario la hora que el usuario selecciona de un radio button, el array de las horas se la paso de la siguiente forma:

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($reserva)
            ->add('horaReserva', 'choice', [
                'choices'=> $horasDisponibles,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,

                ]
            )
```

En la plantilla twig lo muestro de la siguiente forma:

```
{{ form_widget(form.horaReserva, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
```

Y esto lo que muestra la web

`<input type="radio" id="form_horaReserva_0" name="form[horaReserva]" required="required" value="0">
<label for="form_horaReserva_0" class="required">9:00</label>`

El caso es que al guardarlo en la base de datos me lo guarda con valor 0, habría alguna manera de cambiar el campo value desde el controlador y la plantilla para que el campo value tenga como valor la hora?

Aquí se ven las horas disponibles:

[image: Formulario]

Por lo cual el envío de los datos del array se hace correctamente y muestra los datos bien. Pero al renderizar la plantilla añade una campo value=0 y eso es lo que se guarda en la base de datos al enviar el formulario

[image: BBDD]

Este es el resultado al guardarlo ,debería guardar la hora sin embargo guarda la posición del radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione cuando en `value` **aparecía 0,1,2** por las posiciones de cada elemento del array lo he solucionado creando un array auxiliar y combinandolo de esta forma:

```
$horasClaveValor=array_combine($horasDisponibles, $horasDisponibles);
```

De esa forma siempre me tendra de una forma dinámica los mismos valores tanto en clave como en valor.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de la entidad

```
    $hora_reserva;
    public function __construct()
    {    
        $this->hora_reserva=new DateTime(); 
    }
```

Comment: La cosa que el formulario recoge como valor el campo value de la plantilla pero si muestra bien la hora el problema es a la hora de guardar la hora escogida, te adjunto un par de imágenes para que lo veas mejor.